# Flex/Flexicious UI Bug with Firefox v19

Tags: apache-flex, firefox, firefox-addon, flexicious

We have a Flex program which uses Flexicious grids and have recently upgraded to Firefox v19.0.  We have found that if the Firefox browser has a theme on it, we encounter an issue:  If you are working in the Flex program, everything is fine, but if you switch to another tab and then switch back, the Flex application's UI will no longer update until an external event occurs (i.e. mouseover a hyperlink or browser button).  If you remove the Firefox theme and do the same thing, everything works normally again.  We have not been able to recreate the issue with other pure Flash programs on the net, but the problem does happen if we go to the 'Demos' page on the Flexicious website.  Has anyone experienced similar problems or have any ideas on how to fix it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with firefox. A number of flash based demos (including tourdeflex and youtube) are having this problem.